# Can QueryPerformanceCounter() or Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() return the same value in subsequent calls?

Tags: c#, windows, uniqueidentifier, performancecounter

[`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp%28VS.80%29.aspx) both return the tick count from one of the processors. I'd like to use the returned 64-bit integer value as a unique ID and I wonder if it's possible that these functions return the same value when they're called multiple times in a process.

My process would run for few hours at most at a time and these unique IDs are only used temporarily - they're not saved in a database, for example. The above functions would be called several times but with other function calls in between.

The documentation states that it's possible that a motherboard doesn't support high-performance timers but all I've worked with had this support. My code would only run on 32-bit or 64-bit server hardware where I believe high-performance timers are always supported anyway (I'm not sure, though).

I could write a small test program to test it but that test would only be valid on my own computer so I'm looking for a more definitive answer, if one is available.

**Edit**: I know these functions are not *designed* to generate unique IDs but as long as they generate ever-increasing values, it's fine. I'm asking this question not only for technical reason but out of curiosity as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the functions designed to return unique IDs. In fact it is likely 2 subsequent calls will return the same value.

For unique identifiers consider using [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) or simply have counter with (interlocked) increment on each "give me ID" call.

Proof of concept for "QueryPerformanceCounter" returns the same value:

```
class Test
{
    void Main()
    {
    long start1;    
    long start2;
    QueryPerfCounter.QueryPerformanceCounter(out start1);
    QueryPerfCounter.QueryPerformanceCounter(out start2);

    System.Console.WriteLine(start1);
    System.Console.WriteLine(start2);
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32")]
    public static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);
}
```

Comment: I know they're not *designed* tp return unique IDs but if they return ever-increasing values, that's fine. Why do you say they're likely to return identical values?

Comment: Both show current value of a timer - 2 subsequent calls likly to show the same "time" - run sample in the edited answer to see results.

Comment: @xxbbcc when it is trivially easy to use methods that are designed to generate unique ids why would you go out of your way to use methods that aren't designed to do so?

Comment: I'm not using them in the same situation - that's why I mentioned that there are function calles in between two calls to these functions. I'll run your example as I've never actually seen QueryPerformanceCounter return the same value twice but then I've never actually called it multiple times right after each other.

Comment: @Yaur I'm looking at these simply because they return 64-bit integers. Since I only need temporary IDs (not something saved), generating a `GUID` is likely slower and uses more space. I use `GUID`-s as IDs in other places. I'm also curious if it's possible to see duplicate values using these functions. If these functions are not reliable in my situation (which I doubt), I'll just use a static counter instead.

Comment: It is totally your call. Your questions was - "can they return the same value" - the answer is yes, but it may be perfectly fine for your case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Lol, I guess you're right. I may just switch over to using a static counter instead, since I don't know the precise time difference between calls.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use it for IDs, you need to combine this value with other "random" number. But for precision you need to call `QueryPerformanceCounter()` , not `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()`.

Comment: -1. Both return the same value see [Stopwatch.GetTimestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp(v=vs.100).aspx).